# Download files in Xamarin.Forms WebView in iOS?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, webview, xamarin.ios, wkwebview

I can download files in Xamarin.forms in Android using a custom renderer, however in iOS I'm not sure how to set a "listener" to the webview when the user clicks a download link. Should I write a renderer too? Because with the code below the renderer gets the url as "null" (the event gets called before the view-model initializes, so the url property is not set. Thus rendering a blank empty webview screen. Is there another way to do this?

```
      [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(WebView), typeof(MyWebViewRenderer_iOS))]
    namespace MPS.Libertas.Mobile.iOS.Renderers 
    {
        public class MyWebViewRenderer_iOS : ViewRenderer<WebView, WKWebView>
        {
            WKWebView _wkWebView;
           
            protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<WebView> e)
            {
                base.OnElementChanged(e);
    
                if (Control == null)
                {
                    var config = new WKWebViewConfiguration();
                    _wkWebView = new WKWebView(Frame, config);
                    SetNativeControl(_wkWebView);
                }
             }
        }
    }
```

Comment: you can try to implement the [webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:decisionHandler: | Apple Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wknavigationdelegate/1455641-webview?language=objc) for the wkwebview, and try to set [WKNavigationActionPolicyDownload | Apple Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wknavigationactionpolicy/wknavigationactionpolicydownload?language=objc).  In addition, could you please show a download link so I can test it in the ios webview?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm also trying to download files from a custom webview in ios but can't seem to find any information on how to achieve it.

Comment: @TylerWanta we ended changing the need to use a WebView and instead we call the Safari interal app in iOS and the Chrome internal app in Android, loading the desired URL, and then the app itsfel handles the download in a better way than to implement it in a webview. That's what I would suggest unless you really need a Webview, with a webview I don't know if it is possible.

Comment: I managed to get it to work by attaching a custom script to the webview that listens for ajax events and then passes the needed data back to the webview for further work.